# Can I access individual items in computed observables without using foreach binding?

Tags: knockout.js

So far I am able to use `foreach binding` to get specific items to the UI.

Is it possible to access multiple individual items via a computed observable and an `observableArray()` without using `foreach binding`?

Example: This gets me the `fullName`:

```
this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);
```

Using the code below and passing an observableArray to the computed observable, can I access individual elements without a foreach binding?

```
    self.persons = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(listOfPersons(), function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    });
```

Then bind individual persons in `self.persons`.

Comment: Can you explain more what the end result should look like? What/how do you want to display from the listOfPersons?

Comment: I am simply thinking about other creative ways to use a computed observable. For example: I can place additional logic in the anonymous function and bind individual elements without foreach in the UI. Or use computed as a "watch mechanism." I know I can subscribe, but I am just looking at other ways.

Comment: Is this a continuation of your other question? `self.persons` is a computed that returns an array, if you only care about a particular person in the array (like the first one) then you could just bind to `persons[0]`.

Comment: @CrimsonChris: Thanks: But how will I get this to the UI? Don't I need to specify a source? Forgive my ignorance to knockout. but I cannot do: `data-bind="persons[0].personId"`

Comment: I think you're asking for the [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html). `data-bind="with: persons[0]"`

Comment: Alternatively, you could have just a `selectedPerson` observable/computed.

Comment: Very interesting: Per your suggestion, I passed the click parameter to a new array observable and now I am able to bind using the observable without `foreach`. Not quite the answer but very very fascinating for other areas. If you propose as an answer, I will accept it.